# Failed to find SetWindowsHookEx procedure in user32.dll

Tags: windows, winapi, go, setwindowshookex

OS: Windows 10 64bit
Go version: **go version go1.7 windows/amd64**

I get following error message when runing code. I tried to run it with administrators prividge, but still not work.

I referenced following links,

https://github.com/AllenDang/w32

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx

```
panic: Failed to find SetWindowsHookEx procedure in user32.dll: The specified procedure could not be found.
goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x4a7980, 0xc04206c3f0)
    C:/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1af
golang.org/x/sys/windows.(*LazyProc).mustFind(0xc04206c240)
    D:/repos/src/golang.org/x/sys/windows/dll_windows.go:286 +0x71
golang.org/x/sys/windows.(*LazyProc).Call(0xc04206c240, 0xc04203e480, 0x4, 0x4, 0xc042036058, 0x0, 0xc04206c360, 0xc04202def8)
    D:/repos/src/golang.org/x/sys/windows/dll_windows.go:307 +0x36
main.SetWindowsHookEx(0xd, 0x4cab20, 0x0, 0xc000000000, 0x4bfe15)
    d:/repos/src/github.com/quchunguang/trygo/demos/demo_windows_hook/main.go:85 +0xac
main.Start()
    d:/repos/src/github.com/quchunguang/trygo/demos/demo_windows_hook/main.go:147 +0x52
main.main()
    d:/repos/src/github.com/quchunguang/trygo/demos/demo_windows_hook/main.go:166 +0x1b
exit status 2
Process exiting with code: 1
```

My code here.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    //~ "time"
    "unsafe"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

// String returns a human-friendly display name of the hotkey
// such as "Hotkey[Id: 1, Alt+Ctrl+O]"
var (
    user32                  = windows.NewLazySystemDLL("user32.dll")
    procSetWindowsHookEx    = user32.NewProc("SetWindowsHookEx")
    procLowLevelKeyboard    = user32.NewProc("LowLevelKeyboardProc")
    procCallNextHookEx      = user32.NewProc("CallNextHookEx")
    procUnhookWindowsHookEx = user32.NewProc("UnhookWindowsHookEx")
    procGetMessage          = user32.NewProc("GetMessageW")
    procTranslateMessage    = user32.NewProc("TranslateMessage")
    procDispatchMessage     = user32.NewProc("DispatchMessageW")
    keyboardHook            HHOOK
)

const (
    WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13
    WH_KEYBOARD    = 2
    WM_KEYDOWN     = 256
    WM_SYSKEYDOWN  = 260
    WM_KEYUP       = 257
    WM_SYSKEYUP    = 261
    WM_KEYFIRST    = 256
    WM_KEYLAST     = 264
    PM_NOREMOVE    = 0x000
    PM_REMOVE      = 0x001
    PM_NOYIELD     = 0x002
    WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 513
    WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 516
    NULL           = 0
)

type (
    DWORD     uint32
    WPARAM    uintptr
    LPARAM    uintptr
    LRESULT   uintptr
    HANDLE    uintptr
    HINSTANCE HANDLE
    HHOOK     HANDLE
    HWND      HANDLE
)

type HOOKPROC func(int, WPARAM, LPARAM) LRESULT

type KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT struct {
    VkCode      DWORD
    ScanCode    DWORD
    Flags       DWORD
    Time        DWORD
    DwExtraInfo uintptr
}

// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162805.aspx
type POINT struct {
    X, Y int32
}

// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644958.aspx
type MSG struct {
    Hwnd    HWND
    Message uint32
    WParam  uintptr
    LParam  uintptr
    Time    uint32
    Pt      POINT
}

func SetWindowsHookEx(idHook int, lpfn HOOKPROC, hMod HINSTANCE, dwThreadId DWORD) HHOOK {
    ret, _, _ := procSetWindowsHookEx.Call(
        uintptr(idHook),
        uintptr(syscall.NewCallback(lpfn)),
        uintptr(hMod),
        uintptr(dwThreadId),
    )
    return HHOOK(ret)
}

func CallNextHookEx(hhk HHOOK, nCode int, wParam WPARAM, lParam LPARAM) LRESULT {
    ret, _, _ := procCallNextHookEx.Call(
        uintptr(hhk),
        uintptr(nCode),
        uintptr(wParam),
        uintptr(lParam),
    )
    return LRESULT(ret)
}

func UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk HHOOK) bool {
    ret, _, _ := procUnhookWindowsHookEx.Call(
        uintptr(hhk),
    )
    return ret != 0
}

func GetMessage(msg *MSG, hwnd HWND, msgFilterMin uint32, msgFilterMax uint32) int {
    ret, _, _ := procGetMessage.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(msg)),
        uintptr(hwnd),
        uintptr(msgFilterMin),
        uintptr(msgFilterMax))
    return int(ret)
}

func TranslateMessage(msg *MSG) bool {
    ret, _, _ := procTranslateMessage.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(msg)))
    return ret != 0
}

func DispatchMessage(msg *MSG) uintptr {
    ret, _, _ := procDispatchMessage.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(msg)))
    return ret
}

func LowLevelKeyboardProc(nCode int, wParam WPARAM, lParam LPARAM) LRESULT {
    ret, _, _ := procLowLevelKeyboard.Call(
        uintptr(nCode),
        uintptr(wParam),
        uintptr(lParam),
    )
    return LRESULT(ret)
}

func Start() {
    // defer user32.Release()
    keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
        (HOOKPROC)(func(nCode int, wparam WPARAM, lparam LPARAM) LRESULT {
            if nCode == 0 && wparam == WM_KEYDOWN {
                fmt.Println("key pressed:")
                kbdstruct := (*KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)(unsafe.Pointer(lparam))
                code := byte(kbdstruct.VkCode)
                fmt.Sprintf("%q", code)
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(keyboardHook, nCode, wparam, lparam)
        }), 0, 0)
    var msg MSG
    for GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) != 0 {

    }
    //~ for {
    //~
    //~ GetMessage(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(msg)), 0, 0, 0)
    //~ TranslateMessage(msg)
    //~ DispatchMessage(msg)
    //~ // fmt.Println("key pressed:")
    //~
    //~ }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyboardHook)
    keyboardHook = 0
}

func main() {
    Start()
}
```

Comment: It is "SetWindowsHookExW", note the extra W.  Same idea as GetMessageW et al, you want the Unicode version of the function.  It will now fail on the next one, "LowLevelKeyboardProc" is not an exported function, merely a prototype for the callback function.  Just delete that one.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

// String returns a human-friendly display name of the hotkey
// such as "Hotkey[Id: 1, Alt+Ctrl+O]"
var (
    user32                  = windows.NewLazySystemDLL("user32.dll")
    procSetWindowsHookEx    = user32.NewProc("SetWindowsHookExW")
    procCallNextHookEx      = user32.NewProc("CallNextHookEx")
    procUnhookWindowsHookEx = user32.NewProc("UnhookWindowsHookEx")
    procGetMessage          = user32.NewProc("GetMessageW")
    procTranslateMessage    = user32.NewProc("TranslateMessage")
    procDispatchMessage     = user32.NewProc("DispatchMessageW")
    keyboardHook            HHOOK
)

const (
    WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13
    WH_KEYBOARD    = 2
    WM_KEYDOWN     = 256
    WM_SYSKEYDOWN  = 260
    WM_KEYUP       = 257
    WM_SYSKEYUP    = 261
    WM_KEYFIRST    = 256
    WM_KEYLAST     = 264
    PM_NOREMOVE    = 0x000
    PM_REMOVE      = 0x001
    PM_NOYIELD     = 0x002
    WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 513
    WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 516
    NULL           = 0
)

type (
    DWORD     uint32
    WPARAM    uintptr
    LPARAM    uintptr
    LRESULT   uintptr
    HANDLE    uintptr
    HINSTANCE HANDLE
    HHOOK     HANDLE
    HWND      HANDLE
)

type HOOKPROC func(int, WPARAM, LPARAM) LRESULT

type KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT struct {
    VkCode      DWORD
    ScanCode    DWORD
    Flags       DWORD
    Time        DWORD
    DwExtraInfo uintptr
}

// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162805.aspx
type POINT struct {
    X, Y int32
}

// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644958.aspx
type MSG struct {
    Hwnd    HWND
    Message uint32
    WParam  uintptr
    LParam  uintptr
    Time    uint32
    Pt      POINT
}

func SetWindowsHookEx(idHook int, lpfn HOOKPROC, hMod HINSTANCE, dwThreadId DWORD) HHOOK {
    ret, _, _ := procSetWindowsHookEx.Call(
        uintptr(idHook),
        uintptr(syscall.NewCallback(lpfn)),
        uintptr(hMod),
        uintptr(dwThreadId),
    )
    return HHOOK(ret)
}

func CallNextHookEx(hhk HHOOK, nCode int, wParam WPARAM, lParam LPARAM) LRESULT {
    ret, _, _ := procCallNextHookEx.Call(
        uintptr(hhk),
        uintptr(nCode),
        uintptr(wParam),
        uintptr(lParam),
    )
    return LRESULT(ret)
}

func UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk HHOOK) bool {
    ret, _, _ := procUnhookWindowsHookEx.Call(
        uintptr(hhk),
    )
    return ret != 0
}

func GetMessage(msg *MSG, hwnd HWND, msgFilterMin uint32, msgFilterMax uint32) int {
    ret, _, _ := procGetMessage.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(msg)),
        uintptr(hwnd),
        uintptr(msgFilterMin),
        uintptr(msgFilterMax))
    return int(ret)
}

func TranslateMessage(msg *MSG) bool {
    ret, _, _ := procTranslateMessage.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(msg)))
    return ret != 0
}

func DispatchMessage(msg *MSG) uintptr {
    ret, _, _ := procDispatchMessage.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(msg)))
    return ret
}

func Start() {
    // defer user32.Release()
    keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
        (HOOKPROC)(func(nCode int, wparam WPARAM, lparam LPARAM) LRESULT {
            if nCode == 0 && wparam == WM_KEYDOWN {
                fmt.Println("key pressed:")
                kbdstruct := (*KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)(unsafe.Pointer(lparam))
                code := rune(kbdstruct.VkCode)
                fmt.Printf("%q", code)
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(keyboardHook, nCode, wparam, lparam)
        }), 0, 0)
    var msg MSG
    for GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) != 0 {
        // TranslateMessage(msg)
        // DispatchMessage(msg)
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyboardHook)
    keyboardHook = 0
}

func main() {
    Start()
}
```